# Unable to install cURL 7.54.0 on MacOS Catalina 10.15.7

Tags: macos, curl

I'm trying to install a specific version of cURL instead of the latest version (through homebrew). I've extracted Curl 7.54.0 source and executed the following commands

```
./configure --prefix=$HOME/curl
make
make install
```

Getting error in second command as follows

```
connect.c:1086:12: error: 'connectx' is only available on macOS 10.11 or newer
      [-Werror,-Wunguarded-availability]
      rc = connectx(sockfd, &endpoints, SAE_ASSOCID_ANY,
           ^~~~~~~~
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk/usr/include/sys/socket.h:723:5: note: 
      'connectx' has been marked as being introduced in macOS 10.11 here, but
      the deployment target is macOS 10.8.0
int connectx(int, const sa_endpoints_t *, sae_associd_t, unsigned int,
    ^
connect.c:1086:12: note: enclose 'connectx' in a __builtin_available check to
      silence this warning
      rc = connectx(sockfd, &endpoints, SAE_ASSOCID_ANY,
           ^~~~~~~~
1 error generated.
make[2]: *** [libcurl_la-connect.lo] Error 1
make[1]: *** [all] Error 2
make: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
```

Although current MacOS version is higher than 10.11, unable to determine the rootcause of this error.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who brushes upon this issue in the future. The easy solution is to pass in `-Wno-error` in CFLAGS.

The final command is `make CFLAGS=-Wno-error`.